# Raspberry pi 3 model B doesn't boot the android things OS

Tags: raspberry-pi3, android-things

I recently bought vilros Raspberry pi ultimate project kit.In which I received one Raspberry pi 3 model B and 32GB Sd card preloaded with Raspbian OS.

But to work with android things OS instead of Raspbian OS I bought another samsung 16GB sd card and flashed it with the latest android things OS (version 5.1).

Now the problem is that,when I insert sd card (flashed with android things OS) then Raspberry pi doesn't boots up but when I insert the Raspbian OS loaded sd card then Raspberry pi boots up properly.

I need help.Please tell me what should I do.

Comment: Android Things Preview 5.1 is supported, so perhaps you have another issue. I presume you've been through the quick start guide
 (https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/raspberrypi.html). What output do you see via the serial port?

Comment: How do you know it isn't loading? Did you try a second SD card?

Comment: it's not loading bcz it's not give me any display or ACT light. but 4.1 is working good on the same environment without changing any sd card...

Comment: Your SD card needs to be class 10. Did you verify that?